# Circle with more than one "marking"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was experimenting with

```
\draw[
     decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow[scale=2]{<}}},
     postaction={decorate}
     ] 
     (0,0) circle (2);
```

and replaced it with

```
\draw[
     decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow[scale=2]{<}}, 
       mark=at position 0.62 with {\fill circle (2pt);}},
     postaction={decorate}
     ] 
     (0,0) circle (2);
```

i.e. I am trying to put several markings along the circle.

At first I thought I was doing it correctly, just to notice that this doesn't answer my concern 100% as this implementation somehow ruined the alignment of the markings, i.e. either the arrow or the point is off the circle and not really along the circle.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My temporary fix is to just duplicate `\draw` with one having the arrow and the other the point. But is there a neater way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: At least replace the second `\draw` with a `\path` or remove the `postaction` (so that the path is only drawn once). Does it help if you switch the order of the `mark`s (so that `0.62` comes before `0.75`)?

Comment: `\path` is a good suggestion! Now after rearranging it as you said, it seems to work now. I find it strange though... But at least now both the point and the arrow align nicely along the circle! Thanks pal!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - you're correct. Properly ordering the position does the job! Can you please write that as the answer to my question so we can officially settle my question? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PGFmanual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=328) states on page 328 that

> [i]t is possible to give the `mark` option several times, which causes several markings to be applied. In this case, however, it is necessary that the positions on the path are in increasing order. That is, it is not allowed (and will result in chaos) to have a marking that lies earlier on the path to follow a marking that is later on the path.

Thus, you need to do exactly this:

```
\draw[
  decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.62 with {\fill circle [radius=+2pt]);},
    mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow[scale=2]{<}}},
  postaction={decorate}
 ] (0,0) circle [radius=2];
```

---

Of course, you could just do

```
\fill (.62*360:2) circle [radius=+2pt];
```

for the circular marking, but that is another topic.